# How to "listen" for changes to a specific object with simperium

Tags: ios, core-data, simperium

I wonder if you can help me to understand how to make this code "`listen`" to changes from `simperium`. When using `NSFetchedResultsController` it all happens automatically, but how would I do with the following code? Tried to read the document but it was not really clear to me.

```
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kPersonEntity inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == queen"];
NSArray *array = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if(array.count > 0) {
    _queen = (Person *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm lost. what is exactly the object you are trying to listen to changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notifications and act accordingly. Once Simperium processes and saves any changes, you'll receive a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification. Listen for it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextSaved:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:ctx];
```

Then, in your `contextSaved:` method, you filter out the objects you care about

```
    - (void)contextSaved:(NSNotification *)n
    {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [n userInfo];
        NSSet *objects = <see NSManagedObjectContext Change Notification User Info Keys>
        <filter/process objects>
    }
```

Also, don't forget to `removeObserver`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Great, thanks, now I understand how it works, just using `handleContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` instead and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to take a look at `SPBucketDelegate.h`. You can set the `delegate` on any `SPBucket` and receive a variety of notifications directly from Simperium.

This approach is preferred because it ensures you won't be able to adversely affect the data management Simperium is performing behind the scenes.